# How to reformat a video so it can be seen in an html webpage using <iframe>?

Tags: html, video, iframe, youtube

I am using the  tag and some youtube videos show up but the specific video I want isn't in the correct format.

This is the tag with a random video (is working).

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

This is with the video I want (not working).

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fJEFi3ccwI">
</iframe>
```

Can someone please help me reformat?

Comment: How do you know it's not correct format? All file uploads are converted by Youtube into formats like MP4, webM, ,3GP, m4a or mp3 on their servers... Is there any error message? What exactly can  we help you fix?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you simply mean re-format the video URL?

Try as :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9fJEFi3ccwI">
</iframe>
```

Let me know if this works how you wanted?